# how can i calculate the ratio in a data frame for all sub levels between two categories

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe

I am trying to calculate ratio of values for every sub category in a dataframe which has two levels of index

Using python 3 and pandas

```
arrays = [np.array(['numerator', 'numerator', 'denominator', 'denominator']),
         np.array(['A', 'B', 'A', 'B' ])]

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 4), index=[n for n in range(10)], columns=arrays)

    numerator                   denominator
        A           B           A           B
0   0.021060    0.150265    -0.798771   0.676246
1   0.490758    -0.310325   -1.632090   -1.246260
```

Want to add another index 'Ratio' which will have the same two levels [A and B] and will have the ratio as the value. i.e.

```
['Ratio']['A'] = ['numerator']['A']/['denominator']['A']

['Ratio']['B'] = ['numerator']['B']/['denominator']['B']
```

Want to do this with a clean code since i need to do this with cases where I can have more levels in the second index i.e. A, B, C, D...

Comment: `u = df['numerator'] / df['denominator']` then fix the column names: `u.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['Ratio'], u.columns])`, lastly concat: `res = pd.concat([df, u], axis=1)`

Comment: This worked and it is dynamic! Thanks a ton!